# Retry attempts on failure when installing scheduled task with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am installing a scheduled task using a PowerShell script, but I would like it to retry 3 times on failure, how can I add this to my scheduled task registration script?

```
$dropLocation = "C:\Tasks\"
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "$dropLocation\Task.exe" 
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 10:15pm
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RestartCount:3
Register-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -TaskName "$taskName" -Settings $Settings -Description "TaskDescription"
```

Comment: You've already done that with `-RestartCount:3`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen True, but that doesn't get the option "If the task fails, restart every:" enabled...
 
http://i.imgur.com/ohGuBWM.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying the retry count is not enough. You have to specify two parameters:
The retry count and the **retry interval**.

To retry up to three times with an interval of 1 minute, your settings should look like this:

```
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -RestartCount:3 -RestartInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 1)
```